# Why am I getting a Kernel error in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm running Python 3.7 in Spyder from Anaconda and from a fresh install am getting this error:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1223, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 309, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 256, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 474, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\kaimajerus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\dsfs\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 395, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(fname, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
pywintypes.error: (50, 'GetFileSecurity', 'The request is not supported.')
```

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/481 related?

Answer (score -1):

If the kernel displays a long error traceback that mentions other packages like ipython , ipykernel , jupyter_client , traitlets or pyzmq , the problem may be an out of date or incompatible version of a dependency package. To fix this, activate the environment and update the key dependencies.